# How to include a total on a unified hover tooltip for a filled area chart in plotly.js?

Tags: plotly.js

I have a [filled area chart in Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/filled-area-plots/) with `hovermode: 'x unified'` set in the layout so that it produces a single hover tooltip.
[image]

I need to add a total to the tooltip. How can I do this? `hovertemplate` only allows me to edit each data rows individual line, but I can't seem to edit the template itself